# Why am I receiving this 'php parse error' when running this php script on my website?

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am using an example script that was provided on a separate forum that would allow me to embed a ticket submission form into one of my webpages.

I downloaded the example script and replaced the relevant data. The problem is that when I run the script I receive an error. The error is saved in a file in the directory that the script is also located.

The error that I receive is:

```
[13-Jan-2015 17:07:37 Europe/London] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /home/sinergqx/public_html/pages/new_ticket.php on line 46
```

When I received the error, I assumed it was just a typo in the script that had been provided so I did exactly what the error message was describing and replaced the `;` with a `)`. This still made no difference.

I am not too sure what the problem is. I am very limited php knowledge so it is hard for me to troubleshoot to much myself.

I searched the error on the internet but found no threads that explained what to do in this situation.

If it helps to see the thread that I was looking at before, then you can look at it by clicking [here](http://tmib.net/using-osticket-1812-api).

Finally, I have provided the code that I am using. This is the exact script that I have uploaded to my website. It is bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
#
# Configuration: Enter the url and key. That is it.
#  url => URL to api/task/cron e.g #  http://yourdomain.com/support/api/tickets.json
#  key => API's Key (see admin panel on how to generate a key)
#  $data add custom required fields to the array.
#
#  Originally authored by jared@osTicket.com
#  Modified by ntozier@osTicket / tmib.net

// If 1, display things to debug.
$debug="0";

// You must configure the url and key in the array below.

$config = array(
        'url'=>'http://support.sinergycraft.net/api/cron.php',  // URL to site.tld/api/tickets.json
        'key'=>'I WOULD PUT MY API HERE'  // API Key goes here
);
# NOTE: some people have reported having to use "http://your.domain.tld/api/http.php/tickets.json" instead.

if($config['url'] === 'http://your.domain.tld/api/tickets.json') {
  echo "<p style=\"color:red;\"><b>Error: No URL</b><br>You have not configured this script with your URL!</p>";
  echo "Please edit this file ".__FILE__." and add your URL at line 18.</p>";
  die();  
}       
if(IsNullOrEmptyString($config['key']) || ($config['key'] === 'PUTyourAPIkeyHERE'))  {
  echo "<p style=\"color:red;\"><b>Error: No API Key</b><br>You have not configured this script with an API Key!</p>";
  echo "<p>Please log into osticket as an admin and navigate to: Admin panel -> Manage -> Api Keys then add a new API Key.<br>";
  echo "Once you have your key edit this file ".__FILE__." and add the key at line 19.</p>";
  die();
}

# Fill in the data for the new ticket, this will likely come from $_POST.
# NOTE: your variable names in osT are case sensiTive. 
# So when adding custom lists or fields make sure you use the same case
# For examples on how to do that see Agency and Site below.
$data = array(
    'name'      =>      'John Doe',  // from name aka User/Client Name
    'email'     =>      'john@gmail.com',  // from email aka User/Client Email
    'phone'     =>      '1234567890',  // phone number aka User/Client Phone Number
    'subject'   =>      'Test API message',  // test subject, aka Issue Summary
    'message'   =>      'This is a test of the osTicket API',  // test ticket body, aka Issue Details.
    'ip'        =>      $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], // Should be IP address of the machine thats trying to open the ticket.
    'topicId'   =>      '1'; // the help Topic that you want to use for the ticket --L46
    //'Agency'  =>      '58', //this is an example of a custom list entry. This should be the number of the entry.
    //'Site'    =>      'Bermuda'; // this is an example of a custom text field.  You can push anything into here you want. 
    'attachments' => array()
);

# more fields are available and are documented at:
# https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket-1.8/blob/develop/setup/doc/api/tickets.md

if($debug=='1') {
  print_r($data);
  die();
}

# Add in attachments here if necessary
# Note: there is something with this wrong with the file attachment here it does not work.
$data['attachments'][] =
array('file.txt' =>
        'data:text/plain;base64;'
            .base64_encode(file_get_contents('/file.txt')));  // replace ./file.txt with /path/to/your/test/filename.txt


#pre-checks
function_exists('curl_version') or die('CURL support required');
function_exists('json_encode') or die('JSON support required');

#set timeout
set_time_limit(30);

#curl post
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'osTicket API Client v1.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:', 'X-API-Key: '.$config['key']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($code != 201)
    die('Unable to create ticket: '.$result);

$ticket_id = (int) $result;

# Continue onward here if necessary. $ticket_id has the ID number of the
# newly-created ticket

function IsNullOrEmptyString($question){
    return (!isset($question) || trim($question)==='');
}
?>
```

The only thing that isn't as it would be if I uploaded it is that I have deleted the api key and replaced it with `I WOULD PUT MY API HERE`.

Also, although in the comment section of the code it says to link to `http://your.domain.tld/api/http.php/tickets.json`, this was not in any of my directories so instead I linked it to `http://your.domain.tld/api/http.php/cron.php`. I did this because it said in the commented section at the top it said `url => URL to api/task/cron e.g #  http://yourdomain.com/support/api/tickets.json`.

Does anybody know what I have done wrong as I have done what it said in the error message and I haven't had any luck.

Thanks for anyone's help, it is very much appreciated as I am a real beginner at php.

EDIT:

I did look at line 46 and see the `;` and I replaced it with a `)` which the error message suggested to me was what was wrong but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Can you identify which line is line 46, please.

Comment: A basic understanding PHP syntax would help, especially for arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
'topicId'   =>      '1';
```

to this:

```
'topicId'   =>      '1',
                     //^ You have to use a comma to separate each array element
```

Also for more information about an array see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

And a quote from there:

> An array can be created using the array() language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated key => value pairs as arguments.

Also as a good reference which error means what see this: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/3933332)

Answer (score 2):

```
'topicId'   =>      '1'; // the help Topic that you want to use for the ticket
```

It's in the middle of an array definition, so it should be a `,`, not a `;` or `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just reading your code I found that have a ';' in line 46.

Looking to line 46 I was a ';' where need be a ','. How can I know it? Because it is an array, look to another end-lines of variables in array and you will see that from one value to another you need a ',' to separate them.

So here is your corrected code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
#
# Configuration: Enter the url and key. That is it.
#  url => URL to api/task/cron e.g #  http://yourdomain.com/support/api/tickets.json
#  key => API's Key (see admin panel on how to generate a key)
#  $data add custom required fields to the array.
#
#  Originally authored by jared@osTicket.com
#  Modified by ntozier@osTicket / tmib.net

// If 1, display things to debug.
$debug="0";

// You must configure the url and key in the array below.

$config = array(
        'url'=>'http://support.sinergycraft.net/api/cron.php',  // URL to site.tld/api/tickets.json
        'key'=>'I WOULD PUT MY API HERE'  // API Key goes here
);
# NOTE: some people have reported having to use "http://your.domain.tld/api/http.php/tickets.json" instead.

if($config['url'] === 'http://your.domain.tld/api/tickets.json') {
  echo "<p style=\"color:red;\"><b>Error: No URL</b><br>You have not configured this script with your URL!</p>";
  echo "Please edit this file ".__FILE__." and add your URL at line 18.</p>";
  die();  
}       
if(IsNullOrEmptyString($config['key']) || ($config['key'] === 'PUTyourAPIkeyHERE'))  {
  echo "<p style=\"color:red;\"><b>Error: No API Key</b><br>You have not configured this script with an API Key!</p>";
  echo "<p>Please log into osticket as an admin and navigate to: Admin panel -> Manage -> Api Keys then add a new API Key.<br>";
  echo "Once you have your key edit this file ".__FILE__." and add the key at line 19.</p>";
  die();
}

# Fill in the data for the new ticket, this will likely come from $_POST.
# NOTE: your variable names in osT are case sensiTive. 
# So when adding custom lists or fields make sure you use the same case
# For examples on how to do that see Agency and Site below.
$data = array(
    'name'      =>      'John Doe',  // from name aka User/Client Name
    'email'     =>      'john@gmail.com',  // from email aka User/Client Email
    'phone'     =>      '1234567890',  // phone number aka User/Client Phone Number
    'subject'   =>      'Test API message',  // test subject, aka Issue Summary
    'message'   =>      'This is a test of the osTicket API',  // test ticket body, aka Issue Details.
    'ip'        =>      $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], // Should be IP address of the machine thats trying to open the ticket.
    'topicId'   =>      '1', // the help Topic that you want to use for the ticket 
    //'Agency'  =>      '58', //this is an example of a custom list entry. This should be the number of the entry.
    //'Site'    =>      'Bermuda'; // this is an example of a custom text field.  You can push anything into here you want. 
    'attachments' => array()
);

# more fields are available and are documented at:
# https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket-1.8/blob/develop/setup/doc/api/tickets.md

if($debug=='1') {
  print_r($data);
  die();
}

# Add in attachments here if necessary
# Note: there is something with this wrong with the file attachment here it does not work.
$data['attachments'][] =
array('file.txt' =>
        'data:text/plain;base64;'
            .base64_encode(file_get_contents('/file.txt')));  // replace ./file.txt with /path/to/your/test/filename.txt


#pre-checks
function_exists('curl_version') or die('CURL support required');
function_exists('json_encode') or die('JSON support required');

#set timeout
set_time_limit(30);

#curl post
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'osTicket API Client v1.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:', 'X-API-Key: '.$config['key']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($code != 201)
    die('Unable to create ticket: '.$result);

$ticket_id = (int) $result;

# Continue onward here if necessary. $ticket_id has the ID number of the
# newly-created ticket

function IsNullOrEmptyString($question){
    return (!isset($question) || trim($question)==='');
}
?>
```

Comment: The initial line has too much indentation for it to be recognised as a proper shebang. Thus, it is unlikely to work when executed from the command line.